# Can't load an image inside my React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but this image shows up broken when I render the page.

Project Directory Structure is:

```
root
    src
       client
           components
                myComponent.js
    ext
       assets
           logo.js
```

**myComponent.js**

```
import {Component,Store} from 'reactivate';

const CompanyDetail = Component({
    store: Store('./company'),
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='ft-companyDetail'>
                <div id="header">
                    <div class="panel vertical-space">
                        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=1650%C3%97300&w=1650&h=300" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="logo" class="panel vertical-space">
                        <img src="../../ext/assets/logo.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

export default CompanyDetail;
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express(),
    port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('client'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('Sorry, Page Not Found');
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Ready on port %d', port);
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When the page renders, I get a broken image.  I assume you should be able to load images like normal with  and I've tried to troubleshoot the image path with no luck.

Comment: Could you please inspect the broken image in the browser and see which path it refers?

Comment: Another solution to the problem.. refer the image in your CSS..

Comment: here's what it looks like when inspecting it in the browser: http://localhost:3000/ext/assets/logo.png

Comment: yea ultimately I'll probably refer to the image from my css but right now just hard coding it to get a component working then I'll refactor and make it more clean

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are serving static files from client folder.

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
```

So your path  localhost:3000/ext/assets/logo.png is failing.  Hopefully you will get the same error when you try to load the above url from your browser.

You may need to move the ext folder inside client folder.

The better approach is to use Webpack. https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server root is `/src` and is not serving the ext directory.
Your have to use the ext directory in your express server config

```
var path = require('path');
app.use('/ext', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../ext')));
```

Comment: do I really need to use path?

Comment: path is resolving the absolute path from those string concatenations. It is recommended to use [path](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to).